# inkscape: split paths obtained from path-effects

Tags: inkscape, path-effects

Using Inkscape 1.3, I generated a path and made copies using the `rotate copies` path effect (*c.f.:* picture). Now I would like to make individual changes to those copies like changing the color of one arrow. I tried the `break apart` and `Split Path` tools with no success.

More generally, I would like to be able to interact with a modified path like a basic one.
Let's say I apply any path effect to a path, how to keep the appearance, making Inkscape forget the process of building it. Therefore making it possible to behave like any standard path.
[image: How the split the result of Rotate copies]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Inkscape version 1.3, you can apply path-effects directly inside the 'Path Effects' panel by clicking on the arrow button next to the effect name, opening a menu where you can select 'Flatten':

[image: Path Effects panel with 'Flatten' menu-item highlighted]

If you have multiple effects, you can even choose to flatten only up to a specific one in the list, keeping any effects after that as they are.

Alternatively (and in earlier versions), you can apply all path-effects at once by using 'Path → Object to Path'. After that, you can use 'Break Apart' and 'Split Path' like normal.

Comment: +1, but just to note that the behaviour of Flatten is a little different from *Path > Object to Path*.  Flattening will cut out all overlaps, but object to path won't.

Comment: @BillyKerr You're thinking of the 'Path → Flatten' operation. The maybe misleadingly named option inside the 'Path Effects' panel only applies the path-effects to the path-data.

Comment: Oh, you're right it's not the same as Path > Flatten.  However, I just tried it a couple of times, but it didn't work well for me at all. Caused Inkscape to crash the first time. Second time I tried it, it didn't flatten the effects at all, and instead deleted the rotated shapes, perhaps because I had multiple grouped objects, then a rotation path effect added to that.  Looks a bit buggy to be honest.  I'd just stick with Object to Path for now.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for.